# ALSA: mixing input source to output and vice-versa

Tags: alsa, alsamixer

I'm looking forward to have Linux system with GPU-passthrough Windows VM.

Since the emulated sound device from QEMU/KVM is not very good, Windows VM will have USB-passthrough sound device and send Windows's internal sound playing to Linux host's sound device via Optical SPDIF 24-bit/192KHz. Then alsamixer from Linux host will mix this optical input to the host's output audio stream and send to speaker connected to host's sound device.

But also, Linux host also sends its internal audio playing and microphone inputs, mixed by alsamixer too, via Optical SPDIF 24-bit/192KHz. Then Windows VM will use this as broadcasting audio source for Twitch or Discord, mixing with VM's internal audio playing via Windows-part software mixer.

Since I have no experience with alsamixer, or any software audio mixer, I don't even know whether it is going to work or not, how to do this, nor how much cpu power will be needed for this. Also I want this software mixing by very low latency(suitable for gaming).

Any help will be appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: How do you know the "emulated sound device is not very good"? Have you e.g. tried the `hda` (Intel HD audio, as found on most modern systems) device? Also, I am confused how this is going to work. You have two sound cards with Optical SPDIF, one of them for the guest (the USB one), one for the host? Then host and guest communicate via those cards (instead of using the virtual soundcard), and you expect low latency? Not going to happen. You can certainly set this up, using the hardware mixers on the card, ALSA plugin or Pulseaudio, but not with low latency.

Comment: Could you edit your question and describe *why* you want to have it in this particular way? If you want to use the Windows VM for gaming with twitch and discord, wouldn't it be easier to just route a mic into the VM, and don't worry about the "internal audio playing"?

Comment: @dirkt Because with the Intel HDA emulation of QEMU/KVM, when playing audio from both Windows and Linux at the same time, it makes cracking noise due to sampling issue(as far as I know).